# Does Android Development with Ionic Capacitor still not work with Java 9?

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

According to this link, Android Development with Ionic Capacitor does not work with Java 8:

https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/dependencies

> **Android Development**
>   First, the Java 8 JDK must be installed and set to the default if you have other versions of the JDK installed. Java 9 does not work at the moment.

Is this still true? Or is the documentation simply out of date?

Java 9 was released in September, 2017. The current release is Java 12.

I'd think that whatever was the problem has been fixed by now - but I'm not seeing anything to indicate that it has been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android only started working with Java 8 a year or so ago (it was in beta before that for a while).  I wouldn't expect Java 9 for a while-  it isn't a high priority for them, and quite frankly there's still the ongoing Oracle lawsuit that never dies.

Comment: So, it's an Android issue, not an Ionic issue? Good to know who to think black thoughts towards.

Comment: Yes.  Android and its tools don't work with Java9+.  In particular the interpreter doesn't run Java 9 bytecode, so its not just a matter of patching the toolchain to a new compiler.  The Java 7->8 conversion took multiple steps, and parts required v24 of Android.